# Find the number of part tiles required to tile a floor of given dimensions

Tags: c, tile

This program must calculate how many tiles are needed to tile a floor. The tiles are 8 inches by 8 inches. Tiles can be used as a whole or a part of the tile can be used. Only one usable piece can be cut from a tile. That is, if a piece is cut from a tile, the rest of the tile must be thrown away. The program accepts the length and width of the room and returns how many whole tiles are used and how many part tiles are used. The length is given in inches.

I have tried this problem and have no problem obtaining the number of full tiles required but I seem to be having no luck at the number of part tiles required. I have written this program for it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int l, b, full, l1, bl, part;
    float ar2, ar3;
    scanf("%d%d", &l, &b);
    ar3 = (float)(l * b) / 64;
    l1 = l / 8;
    bl = b / 8;
    full = l1 * bl;
    ar2 = ar3 - full;
    part = ar2 * 2;
    printf("%d\n%d", full, part);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ar3=(float)(l*b)/64;`...did you mean `ar3=((float)l*b)/64;`?

Comment: Yeah I tried both and they both produced the same result for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way is to have tiles parallel to the walls. In that case, you can just find the number of tiles necessary in both directions, and the total number of tiles will the the product of those 2 numbers. The trick to get the number of partial tiles is to separately compute the number of whole tiles and then the number of whole *and* partial tiles. Code becomes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int l,b,full,l1,bl,part;
  int partl = 0, partb = 0;

  scanf("%d%d",&l,&b);

  l1=l/8;                       // number of whole tiles
  if ((l % 8) != 0) {
      partl = 1;                // will need one partial at the end
  }
  // second direction
  bl=b/8;
  if ((b % 8) != 0) {
      partb = 1;                // will need one partial at the end
  }
  full=l1*bl;                   // total number of whole tiles
  if (partl) l1 += 1;           // total (including partial) per direction
  if (partb) bl += 1;
  part = l1 * bl - full;        // partial is total - number of whole tiles
  printf("%d\n%d",full,part); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You.
That solved the problem I was having. I had neglected the possible remainders while dividing by 8

Comment: Also thanks for the comments. They really helped me understand. I should start incorporating those in future

Comment: @varunbheemaiah: comments help to read and understand code. When you read code that you had written one year ago, you regret not to have left some comments more....

Comment: You're right. I'm still a beginner at this so every tip is useful :). Thanks

Comment: Simplification: `part = partl * bl + partb * l1 + partl * partb;`

Answer (score 0):

There is either 0 or 1 row of partial tiles in either direction. If there are partial tiles in both directions then there is also a partial corner tile.

You can use the modulus operator, `%` to find if there are any partial tiles:

```
// Calculation of partial tiles
part = 0;
int partL = l%8;
int partB = b%8;

if (partL > 0) {
    part += bl;   // Partial tiles along one edge
}
if (partB > 0) {
    part += l1;   // Partial tiles along the other edge
}
if (partL > 0 && partB > 0) {
    part += 1;   // Partial corner tile;
}
```

**Note:** 
The glyphs for `l` and `1` are often hard to tell apart, so be careful when using them in variable names. If you use them without thought the code will be harder to read.

Comment: Thanks. I will avoid using them in the future to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
width = int(input())
length = int(input())

full_tiles_length=length//8
full_tiles_width =width//8
frac_length = (length/8)%1
frac_width =(width/8)%1 
cl=0
cw=0
if(frac_width!=0 ):
    cw =full_tiles_length
if(frac_length!=0):
    cl =full_tiles_width
print(full_tiles_length*full_tiles_width)
if(cl!=0 and cw!=0):
    print(cl+cw+1)
else:
    print(cl+cw)
```

Comment: I'm afraid `(length/8)%1` is always `0`